# Why don't we use nodpi for all drawables?

Tags: android

I'm not talking about the resource files like .9.png or .xml, but rather image files for icons and backgrounds. Isn't it much easier or more reliable to create a high definition image, put it inside of the nodpi folder, and then use properties like fitXY to fit the image inside a given space? Why go through all the trouble of creating a scaled version for mdpi, hdpi, xdpi, etc?

Comment: Then `fitXY` becomes your new trouble. You will have the exact same issue plus you will have to deal with all the `UI` related issues programmatically. `mdpi, hdpi, xdpi` its a safe way to go, not to mention the performance issues that the Iron Marx & CommonsWare mention in their answers

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by fitXY becoming a new trouble? Right now, its easier for me to just have one high density resource, and using properties like fitXY to completely fill the given space. I don't have to worry about the image being blurry because the wrong density resource was used or the resource itself wasn't the right dimension.

Comment: You have to be worried because `fitXY` won't respect your initial `aspect ratio`. Of course if you have a background image that is not complex then you will not notice the `aspect ratio` issue, but if you try your approach with an image that is complex you will immediately notice the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scaling down a large image to a smaller one before using it as an ImageView's source is more computationally expensive than being able to pull a properly sized one from a proper DPI bucket.

While it may be easier to slap your resources into a single drawable folder and call it good, it will cause performance issues when rendering assets on lower DPI devices, which tend to have less powerful CPUs anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I had an inkling it had something to do with performance.

Comment: Btw does drawable inside `no-dpi` auto scale up/down according to device densities?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar no it doesn't scale.

Answer (score 5):

> Why go through all the trouble of creating a scaled version for mdpi, hdpi, xdpi, etc?

For quality. Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence):

> However, bitmap scaling can result in blurry or pixelated bitmaps, which you might notice in the above screenshots. To avoid these artifacts, you should provide alternative bitmap resources for different densities. For example, you should provide higher-resolution bitmaps for high-density screens and the system will use those instead of resizing the bitmap designed for medium-density screens.

Comment: I understand the point of having different density image resources and that  if you're going from a lower density to a high density, you definitely need different resources. But having just the high density and scaling it down to lower ones would still result in the best quality right? Not factoring in performance here, just quality.

Comment: @HuyT: "But having just the high density and scaling it down to lower ones would still result in the best quality right?" -- no. First, the image may be too complex at high density to get something that is readable when downsampled. Heck, just look at my company name in my Gravatar here on Stack Overflow. Second, the algorithms used by Android for sampling will tend to be optimized for CPU speed and heap usage, and therefore may be lower quality than desktop equivalents.

Comment: I see. So detailing could take hit. Good to know.

Comment: What if I use a decent quality image in my 'nodpi' folder which is big enough to fit in the largest screen size, and don't do any scaling operation through code? Will performance still take a hit? The memory consumed might be high when used in an ldpi device, but let's assume that I have optimized my images to take very less memory. What could go wrong with this approach?

Comment: @Swas_99: "Will performance still take a hit?" -- I can't really answer that. "let's assume that I have optimized my images to take very less memory" -- there is no such concept. Bitmaps all take the same size, based solely on resolution. Your *on disk* size may vary based upon compression algorithms, but that does not matter for the *in memory* size. The only way to control in memory size is to control the resolution or, via `BitmapFactory.Options`, control bit depth.